# Can't replicate 'cross-thread operation not valid' error in unit tests - I don't understand

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, unit-testing, nunit

This is my first Stack question, so apologies in advance if my format or etiquette are a little off.

I've recently been setting up patterns to handle ['cross-thread operation not valid' issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975446/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-asynchronous-delegates-error) when interacting with WinForms controls from a separate thread.

I thought it would be nice to set up a unit test to isolate this and assert that my SynchronisationContext extensions fixed the issue, so I created a simple test Form with one button on it and some code that called 'PerformClick()' from another thread to replicate the issue:

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {           
        using (TestForm form = new TestForm())
        {
            Thread t1 = new Thread(() => Application.Run(form));
            Thread t2 = new Thread(() => form.buttonStart.PerformClick());
            form.Activated += (sender, args) => t2.Start();
            t1.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(1000); //Prevents form from being disposed before 'click' can occur from other thread.
        }                       
    }
```

The test form is literally an empty form with a single button on it. When I ran this code, I got the cross-thread operation exception as expected.

But when I put the code into an NUnit test, the exception does not occur. Here is my unit test:

```
    [Test]
    public void PostToControl_AcrossThreads()
    {           
        //Notes: This code normally generates a cross-thread exception.
        //For some reason, when you run it in the scope of the unit test, the exception is not generated.
        using (TestForm form = new TestForm())
        {
            Thread t1 = new Thread(() => Application.Run(form));
            Thread t2 = new Thread(() => form.buttonStart.PerformClick());
            form.Activated += (sender, args) => t2.Start();
            t1.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(1000); //Prevents form from being disposed before 'click' can occur from other thread.
        }
    }
```

I realized that I had no clear idea why this would occur, so I'm throwing it to the experts :-)

Can anyone enlighten me? What is happening so differently in the unit test compared to running the form natively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is controlled by a property: [Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.checkforillegalcrossthreadcalls.aspx)

By default, it is only true if a debugger is attached, which is the behaviour you are seeing.

Comment: Note that this forces an exception on cross-threading control access. Without this, sometimes it will work fine and sometimes it will fail - This simply makes it fail consistently.

Comment: Perfect! This is great info, thank you very much for your responses.

Comment: @Martaver have you try to debug while you testing by attaching? are you getting exception?

Comment: @UnhandledException, yes when I debug the unit test, the exception occurs - it just gets hidden because it occurs in another thread. I catch the exception like you say, and perform an assertion in the main thread on whether or not the exception was caught. But then, you still have to enable Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls if you want the exception to be raised when you're unit testing without the debugger.

Answer (score 3):

Use something else than `PerformClick()`. For example `form.buttonStart.Text = "This is my form";` or changing positions etc...

The reason is, the method `PerformClick()` only raises the .NET event `Click`. But the problem of cross-thread operation is with windows-message-loop. So if you want "do problem" you must perform some action, which uses the windows-message-loop.

Comment: Thanks TcKs.  I tried both setting the text value and setting the Location of the button and the cross-thread exception still doesn't show, unfortunately.  I don't think the problem is with the control action, since my original code is able to produce the error by just accessing the control, regardless of what you are doing to it.

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone enlighten me? What is happening so differently in the unit
>   test compared to running the form natively?

there is no different.

if you need to check for exception on Nunit better use [Exception Asserts](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=exceptionAsserts&r=2.5.9). otherwise nunit will not show the exceptions for you.

if you not doing assets for exception at least put a try catch block and log the exception you will get the same exception on test case also.

Comment: Thanks UnhandledException, but my problem is that the exception is not being produced in the first place when I run the identical code in the unit test :)  I'm pretty sure it's some obscure threading issue.

Comment: @Martaver have you check using error logging while unit testing? check where exception occur. I'm sure it is the same line.

Comment: On close inspection, you're right :) The exception IS being thrown, however only in debug mode.  Nicholas Butler's answer explains why when you're running unit tests without the debugger the behavior is not exhibited.